# Java, Spring hooking themes properties file to css file

Tags: java, spring, themes

this is how I intialize theme beans:

```
<bean id="themeSource"
class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="resources.theme-" />
</bean>

<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</bean>

<bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

this is my folder stucture:

[image]

these are the inside of my 3 properties files:

```
css=themes/black.css
css=themes/blue.css
css=themes/default.css
```

I have also tried these:

1. css=classpath:themes/default.css
2. css=/themes/default.css
3. css=./themes/default.css

Should the css even be in WEB-INF/classes. I've tried moving it out and in etc, but never quite seemed to get it to work.

Here is how I put it in my JSP:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='css'/>" type="text/css" />
```

This is now my output looks like:

[image]

This is part of JSP:

```
<span style="float: left">
<a href="?theme=default">def</a>
|
<a href="?theme=black">blk</a>
|
<a href="?theme=blue">blu</a>
</span>
```

This is my black.css.

```
body {
    background-color: #888;
    color: white;
}
```

**My problem is, that the css never seems to go on my JSP file. This is probably caused because properties file can not find css file...**
Feel free to ask further info.

Comment: Is the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='css'/>" type="text/css" />` rendered properly with a valid URL being replaced for the `href` attribute?

Comment: @adarshr : sorry, what do you mean exactly, do you mean how I href at my JSP? then i updated my answer a little bit : `<a href="?theme=black">blk</a>
`

Comment: What I meant was, if you do a `view source` on the generated HTML, how do you see the `link` tag?

Comment: @adarshr : oh, I see it as it is in properties file: so when I have `css=themes/black.css` ,  then in html source, it is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/black.css" type="text/css" />
`

Comment: Then clearly the browser won't be able to access it as your `themes` directory is inside WEB-INF which is not accessible.

Comment: @adarshr : so where should I move it and how should i change my properties files accordingly?

Comment: @Jaanus let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2489/discussion-between-adarshr-and-jaanus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do here, was to move my resources(js or css files) to root folder of my project.

The second thing I could do instead, is to create a resource mapping for my css files.

Both would work, but I went with the first solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with this.

`<bean id="themeSource"
class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="resources.theme-" />
</bean>`

According to the Javadoc:

`public void setBasenamePrefix(String basenamePrefix)`

> Set the prefix that gets applied to the ResourceBundle basenames, i.e.
>   the theme names. E.g.: basenamePrefix="test.", themeName="theme" ->
>   basename="test.theme".
>
> Note that ResourceBundle names are effectively classpath locations: As
>   a consequence, the JDK's standard ResourceBundle treats dots as
>   package separators. This means that "test.theme" is effectively
>   equivalent to "test/theme", just like it is for programmatic
>   java.util.ResourceBundle usage.

Also, you're allowed to put the theme properties files inside the WEB-INF/classes folder as written in the Reference Docs.

> By default, the ResourceBundleThemeSource uses an empty base name
>   prefix. As a result, the properties files are loaded from the root of
>   the classpath. Thus you would put the cool.properties theme definition
>   in a directory at the root of the classpath, for example, in
>   /WEB-INF/classes. The ResourceBundleThemeSource uses the standard Java
>   resource bundle loading mechanism, allowing for full
>   internationalization of themes.

I guess the problem in your case is that you've mentioned the path to the css twice.. Once in the `<property name="basenamePrefix" value="resources.theme-" />` and once in the properties file too

```
css=themes/black.css
css=themes/blue.css
css=themes/default.css
```

Comment: I do have theme files in WEB-INF/classes..Isn't the beans only for properties files and properties files is for css? Or what do you reccomend me to fix the problem?

Comment: I think this would work : change it to `<property name="basenamePrefix" value="resources.theme.theme-" />` and change properties file values to `css=black.css` etc..

Comment: And leave all files in the same folder and location they are, right? (folder structure in first post)

Comment: Well I changed them, it did not work. I uploaded the project also, if you're interested, http://char.planet.ee/JPG-program/AntThemeHelloWorld.rar